# drupal database error (layout_builder module Update fix_tempstore_keys Failed:)

Tags: drupal-8

How to solve this issue in drupal 8?
layout_builder module
Update fix_tempstore_keys

> Failed: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\ContextException: The
>   view_mode context is not a valid context. in
>   Drupal\Component\Plugin\ContextAwarePluginBase->getContextDefinition()
>   (line 92 of
>   /home/t8f7rclkg1a0/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/ContextAwarePluginBase.php).

Answer (score 1):

you can remove **tempstore.shared.layout_builder.section_storage.overrides** row from **key_value_expire** table. It just indicates that you have started modifying some layout builder template, but didn't save the override yet. And Drupal update tries to fix it and fails.

Comment: Disable layout builder for that view mode and reenable it. Then override it this time it won't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want a more robust fix, see how this core issue is progressing:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3044211